# Random name generator from JSON file

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

Tired of thinking up random names when following tutorials involving people? So was I.

The code below is the first project I've written in Python. Put simply, it grabs a list of forenames and last-names from an online database, saves them into a dictionary, then writes it to a JSON file. After that, the rest of the code reads the JSON file, chooses a first and last name based on any regex strings passed into the function, then returns the first and last name as a single string, separated by a space.

I've noticed however, this baby is **sloooooow**. I'm talking 150 - 200ms to generate a name. That's 20 seconds to generate a list of 100 names. I know there's huge room for improvement here, but I'm not well versed enough in the standard libraries yet.

Here it is:

```
from codecs import decode
from json import dump, loads
from pathlib import Path
from random import randrange
from re import compile, findall, IGNORECASE
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from urllib import request


DB_FORE = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smashew/NameDatabases/master/NamesDatabases/first%20names/us.txt'
DB_LAST = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smashew/NameDatabases/master/NamesDatabases/surnames/us.txt'


def write_names(dest, url_forename = DB_FORE, url_surname = DB_LAST):
    """
    Writes the names from the database to the given destination.
    :param dest: the name of the destination file. Blank if you want the string returned
    :param url_forename: url containing plain text first names, entries separated by \r\n
    :param url_surname: url containing plain text last names, entries separated by \n
    """
    names = {
        # Last values tend to be buggy, so get rid of them
        'forenames': _get_names(url_forename).split("\r\n")[:-1],
        'surnames': _get_names(url_surname).split("\n")[:-1],
    }

    with open(dest, 'w') as json_file:
        dump(names, json_file, indent = 4, separators = (',', ': '))


def random_name(fmatches = '', smatches = ''):
    """
    Gets a random name in the form "Forename Lastname".
    :param fmatches: a regex string to try to match to a forename
    :param smatches: a regex string to try to match to a surname
    :return: a random name based on the regex inputs, or None if no names were found
    """
    file_name = 'names.json'
    names_file = Path(file_name)
    if not Path(names_file).is_file():
        print(f'{file_name} not found, writing from default database')
        write_names(file_name)
        print('Done!')

    with names_file.open('r') as json_file:
        names = loads(json_file.read())
        first = _choose_name(fmatches, names['forenames'])
        last = _choose_name(smatches, names['surnames'])

        if first is None or last is None:
            return None
        else:
            return first + " " + last


def _get_names(url):
    with request.urlopen(url) as site:
        return str(decode(site.read(), 'utf-8'))


def _choose_name(expr, data):
    if expr is None:
        return data[randrange(0, len(data))]
    else:
        return _random_match(compile(expr, flags = IGNORECASE), data)


def _match_names(expr, data):
    return [name for name in data if findall(expr, name)]


def _random_match(expr, data):
    matches = _match_names(expr, data)
    return matches[randrange(0, len(matches))] if len(matches) > 0 else None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = timer()
    print(random_name('rose', 'an'))
    end = timer()
    print(end - start, '\n')

    start = timer()
    print(random_name(fmatches = '^jo'))
    end = timer()
    print(end - start, '\n')

    start = timer()
    print(random_name(smatches = 'en$'))
    end = timer()
    print(end - start, '\n')

    start = timer()
    print(random_name(fmatches = 'grf'))
    end = timer()
    print(end - start, '\n')

    start = timer()
    print([random_name() for _ in range(10)])
    end = timer()
    print(end - start, '\n')
```

The JSON file (named 'names.json') is in the following format:

```
{
    "forenames": [
        "Aaron",
        "Abbey",
        "Abdul",
        ...
    ],
    "surnames": [
        "Aaberg",
        "Aaby",
        "Aadland",
        ...
    ]
}
```

For reference, there's about 5,000 forenames, and 90,000 surnames... yeah, I'm thinking that has something to do with how slow it is (go figure). Obviously I could speed up the execution significantly by removing a lot of uncommon names, but I want to know if there is any way I can improve the current implementation with the current list of names.

The name generator supports entering regex strings, but I haven't seen any notable performance difference between generating a name with or without regex.

Here's a sample output from running the module:

```
Roseanna Sodeman
0.1488200619749599 

Joette Knorr
0.21161438351850587 

Birdie Tohen
0.15252753028006855 

None
0.21214806850333456 

['Mohammed Koelzer', 'Luvenia Kovalcin', 'Danica Lehnen', 'Chad Mannan', 
'Naomi Kilborne', 'Cami Lydecker', 'Amie Dearson', 'Seema Reiche', 'Ai 
Bruhn', 'Laureen Gitthens']
2.1672272217311948
```

Because I'm a beginner, I would appreciate reviews on both improving the performance of the code, and also my code style (i.e. any standard libraries I could be utilising, any shortcuts such as List Comprehension that I'm missing).

Comment: partly because of  [greedy expressions search in regex is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26214328/why-python-regex-is-so-slow)

Comment: Partly because you are re-reading the JSON file of names every time you generate a name.